# mysql query not running, why?

Tags: php

my code:

```
        <div id='tagbox' style='display: none;'>
        <form method="POST" name="newtagadd">
            <input type="text" name="tagaddbox" class="form-control" style="width: 400px; display: inline;" placeholder="Füge Tags hinzu..."/>
            <label for="submittag" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: orange; display: inline;"></span></label>
            <input type="submit" id="submittag" class="hidden" />
        </form>
        <br/>(Tags mit Komma trennen. Beispiel: tag1,tag2,tag3)
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            require_once("config.php");
            if(isset($_POST['submittag']))
            {
                $tagaddbox = $_POST['tagaddbox'];
                $q = mysql_query("UPDATE img_data SET tags=$tagaddbox, WHERE id=$id") or die (mysql_error());   
            }
        ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php
            echo '<a id="stream-prev" style="display: inline; text-decoration: none;" class="pict" href="image.php?id=$id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>';
            echo '<a id="stream-next" style="display: inline; text-decoration: none;" class="pict" href="image.php?id=$id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>';
        ?>
```

So nothing happens, the page refreshes and if I press f5 i will be asked, if i want to send it again (firefox)

im thankful for every answer.

Comment: Please edit your title to describe the problem.

Comment: If there is no action then it submits back to itself.

Comment: How could anyone possibly answer this with a solution instead of just general guidelines. Someone could just copy paste a php book here and by the end of the "answer" you would probably understand where you went wrong. The answer to this is to revisit what actually went wrong. When you figure out exactly what happened, you will more than likely know how to fix it. And if not, explain exactly what happened here and someone will be able to help.

Comment: but it doesnt even update the table.

Comment: You don't have an input named submittag

Comment: "UPDATE img_data SET tags='" . $tagaddbox . "' WHERE id=$id"

it overwrites the row "tags". Is there any option to NOT overwrite the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper SQL syntax for update does not include a comma between the SET and WHERE clauses

Wrong

> "UPDATE img_data SET tags=$tagaddbox, WHERE id=$id"

Right

> "UPDATE img_data SET tags=$tagaddbox WHERE id=$id"

Also you need a name not just an id on

```
<input type="submit" id="submittag" name="submittag" class="hidden" />
```

Comment: "UPDATE img_data SET tags='" . $tagaddbox . "' WHERE id=$id" it overwrites the row "tags". Is there any option to NOT overwrite the row?

Comment: @Florian Jansen, That's called an insert. Any book (or online tutorial) on SQL will cover the syntax.

Comment: yea, I know. but my table looks like this: 
ID|name|tags|upvotes|downvotes|uploader|time|date

name=imagename.jpg

so if I add a tag and there is a tag in "tags", the new tag overwrites the old one.

Comment: You want to append a tag in an update, `set tags = tags + ', new tag'` or something like that.

Comment: it worked now. 
I SELECT the old tags and used CONCAT:

"UPDATE img_data SET tags=CONCAT('$oldtags, $tagaddbox')"